# Test/verify "keyserver" lines in gpg.conf

Tags: gpg

After I make a change to the `keyserver` lines in `gpg.conf`, is there any way to test that I made no mistakes besides using `gpg --send-keys`?

Comment: what sort of mistakes are you thinking of? The syntax for the configuration? Or having selected a working keyserver?

Comment: Either.  Or both at once.